# É possível usar qualquer linguagem de programação no Windows Azure? Como?

Tags: microsoft-azure

O site do Windows Azure deixa claro e explica como usar várias linguagens de programação. Mas ainda assim, não explica como usar algumas linguagens mais simples, como por exemplo o próprio C++.

Eu sei que o Amazon Web Services pode ser adaptado para outras linguagens, mas e o Windows Azure? Ele permite usar outras linguagens além das listadas no site? E, se sim, qual é o "segredo"?

Comment: `"Linguagens mais simples, como por exemplo o próprio C++"` O sr. deve utilizar apenas Assembly e Brainf*ck em seu dia a dia.

Comment: Como uma linguagem com umas 600 páginas de especificação pode ser simples ehehe? Você não quis dizer linguagem de baixo nível?

Comment: Com "simples" eu quis dizer "mais comuns", afinal todas as plataformas têm uma implementação... mas gostei dos comentários xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Azure possui `Web sites`, que podem rodar nativamente `ASP.NET`, `PHP`, `NodeJS` e `Python` (obrigado @Danimar pela informação), e possui máquinas virtuais, que você pode configurar às suas necessidades. Há diversas imagens de VMs disponíveis para diversos casos:

**APLICAÇÕES ESPECÍFICAS**

Você pode criar web sites a partir da galeria, que implementam um determinado aplicativo como Wordpress, Drupal, etc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**SERVIDORES VIRTUAIS**

Você pode criar VMs e personalizá-las para o uso que quiser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Para o seu caso**, o ideal seria criar uma VM com a imagem adequada (há várias, de vários distribuidores) e fazer a configuração, o que certamente exige um esforço adicional.

**OS PREÇOS**

Seguem os preços praticados, de acordo com o tamanho da sua VM:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi... então eu posso ter a linguagem que eu quiser com uma VM, basta configurá-la do zero. (É claro que isso sai um pouco mais caro.) É isso ou entendi errado?

Comment: É basicamente isso! Mas não há cobrança adicional... Vou atualizar com o valor cobrado por hora!

Comment: Basicamente, assim que vc sobe uma VM, passa a pagar por hora. Ela já vem habilitada para uso via Conexão Remota (para VMs Windows) ou SSH (para VMs Linux).

Comment: A "cobrança adicional" que eu quis dizer é que uma VM é mais cara que um Web Site comum, mas eu entendi o que você quis dizer. Ótima resposta, portanto aceita.

Comment: Você pode se inscrever no programa BizSpark e ter 40% de desconto por 3 anos, além de US$ 150 de créditos no Azure por mês. Não é difícil conseguir ser aceito, basta preencher corretamente os dados no tempo exigido! Levam cerca de um mês pra responder sua aplicação, então tenha paciência... Se inscreve aí! www.microsoft.com/bizspark/‎

Answer (score 1):

Na lista de linguagens pode ser acrescentado Node.js e Python.
O visual studio até possui SDK para poder publicar aplicativos python, php, etc.

http://www.windowsazure.com/pt-br/services/web-sites/

> Os desenvolvedores podem criar novos aplicativos do zero ou implantar
>   aplicativos existentes criados no ASP.NET, PHP, Node.js, Python ou até
>   mesmo no Classic ASP. Você pode incluir um banco de dados quando
>   provisiona um novo site com uma opção de banco de dados SQL ou MySQL.
>   Alternativamente, os desenvolvedores podem começar escolhendo dentre
>   mais de 30 aplicativos de software livre, estruturas e modelos da
>   Galeria de Aplicativos Web, incluindo WordPress, Umbraco, DotNetNuke,
>   Drupal, Django, CakePHP e Express.